# nodejs fs.exists (fs.access) has strange things happen in for-loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, fs

my code:

```
for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    console.log("idx: " + i);

    fs.access('/etc/passwd', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
      console.log(err ? 'no access!'+i : 'can read/write'+i);
    });

    fs.exists('/etc/passwd', (exists) => {
      console.log(exists ? 'it\'s there'+i : 'no passwd!'+i);
    });
}
```

result:
idx: 0
idx: 1
no access!2
it's there2
no access!2
it's there2

why the i =2?
how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key of your problem is the asyncrhony. Both fs methods are asynchronous and will be executed later, and when they are going to be executed the value of i is 2, because the loop has finished.

The easiest way to solve it is changing the declaration of the loop   var by let

```
for(let i=0; i<2; i++)
```

It limits the scope of i to one iteration

Answer (score 2):

[`fs.access`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) and [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) are async calls and when they get their callbacks executed the accumulator has been already set to 2, because of the loop.